# Emit output of hadoop job to a single File

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am processing some data using hadoop which is composed of multiple files. Now, I want hadoop to emit only file in the output. I set the following parameters.

```
    set mapred.reduce.tasks=1;
    set hive.exec.reducers.max = 1;
    set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
    set hive.exec.compress.intermediate=true;
```

But still it doesn't work. Can someone please explain this?

**Update :**

I am setting these parameters in the hive console. Moreover, my output is not written to hdfs but to Amazon s3.

Comment: where do you set these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say because I do not know where you set the parameters. For me the best way to emit only one output file is using `ToolRunner` implementation in your MR job. Good manual can be found here [Hadoop: Implementing the Tool interface for MapReduce driver](http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/hadoop-implementing-the-tool-interface-for-mapreduce-driver/).

Than you can specify number of output files right from CLI like this:

```
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=NumberOfOutputs
```

There is also possibility to use DFS command [-getmerge](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/hdfs_shell.html#getmerge):

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge sourceDirectory OutputFile.txt
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If the input data is huge then setting the reducer to 1 is not advisable. try the dfs -getmerge command.